# PHP+Memcached - how to optimize connections? (dealing with TIME_WAIT)

Tags: php, redis, memcached

I'm using PHP with Memcached. Webserver receives a request, opens a connection to memcached and then does its job. Using memcache**d** standard library.

This creates **in systems under load** a tons of `TIME_WAIT` TCP connections. I have read this can be mitigated by tweaking `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` & `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`. And it does work up to a point.

I've also understood memcached cannot be used with UDP with the current php library.

On a general level, how can this issue be fixed, rather than improved? Like few examples: can I use UDP with Redis? Can I use some kind of persistent connections with memcached?

I just don't understand how can anyone run systems under big load with PHP and memcached.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Redis is TCP. Have you tried using memcached unix socket instead of TCP?

Comment: Do those TIME_WAIT connections pose an _actual, measurable problem_, or are you just looking at the amount and thinking "this can't be right"?

Comment: Yes, I am running into resource exhaustion. I'm trying sockets now :)

Comment: @JoeSlav Let us know if unix sockets solved resource exhaustion issue. Also, what kind of load did you have on your API (requests per second), and were you opening/closing your memcached connection for each request?

Comment: I'm using PHP so I don't see any other way as opening/closing connections for any request (but happy to be proven wrong...that's why I opened this question!). I saw this with around 1000 req/sec (with a tcp_fin_timeout of 30 secs, that exhausts 30k ports pretty quickly). I'll let you know as soon as I get them working (fighting with permissions now..).

Comment: yep, the problem is fixed with socket, thanks for the tip Dimi. if you post an answer i'll accept it!